# Nested routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, sinatra

I am someone who has always liked sinatra better than rails, and has never had to do a large enough scale project that rails was required (all the sources I have read say that rails is better for larger scale projects) and now I do have to do a large scale project. I have gotten very confused with the url structure of rails. What I am trying to do is the rails equivalent of this:

```
get "/" do
    erb :index
end
get "/home" do
    erb :dashboard
end
get "/home/profile" do
    erb :profile
end
get "/home/friends" do
    erb :friends
end
```

In the first one I understand that I should put in `app/routes.rb` I should put `root home#index` and in the `home` controller I should put `def index end`.

In the second one, I understand that I should do the same except replacing index with home.

But for the third and forth ones I have no idea what to do.

Also, is the a RESTful way to do the first two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have this:

```
  resources :home do
    collection do
      get :profile
    end

    collection do
      get :friends
    end
  end
end
```

This will give you routes like this:

```
profile_home_index GET    /home/profile(.:format)  home#profile
friends_home_index GET    /home/friends(.:format)  home#friends
```

The standard way of declaring the root path:

```
root 'home#index'
```

And for the 2nd one, you have to do:

```
get 'home' => 'home#dashboard'
```

which will give you this route:

```
GET    /home(.:format)          home#dashboard
```

One route can be defined in many ways that works. But, Rails has conventions that should be followed while defining routes in your Rails app.

I would highly recommend you to take a look at the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Yes, those are RESTful routes that I defined using `resources` and `collection`, see more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this

```
root 'home#index'
get 'home' => 'home#dashboard'
get 'home/profile' => 'home#profile'
get 'home/friends' => 'home#friends'
```

remember to use the command `rake routes` to see all your routes, where they lead and what their names are (if they have any)

I never understood what RESTful means, so someone else will have to answer that part of your question.

K M Rakibul Islam has shown you what can be called a "resourceful" way to do routes (because it uses the keyword `resources`) but it looks like you're just doing the static pages at this stage, so it's not necessary.

The simplest way to do routes is with this formula:

```
method url => controller::action, as: route_name
```

where `method` can be `get`, `post`, `patch` or `delete` so you can have different actions linked to the same URL depending on the method the request uses.

Putting a name on the route is optional, but it gives you a clean way to use the route in your views (`route_name_path`)

When you start making models then you'll find that using the `resources` keyword comes in handy. Read about it.

Comment: I didn't accept you answer because @KMRakibulIslam's was better but yours was also very helpful. +1